# Creating alternate series in R

Tags: r, sorting

I have a list of

```
-0.5, -0.6, 0.7, 1, 1.5, 3, -5
```

and I would like to sort it as

```
3, -5, 1.5, -0.6, 1, -0.5, 0.7
```

In other words, I would like to sparate the list into positive and negative lists, then sort them **from largest to smallest**, but alternating.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is it a list or a vector?

Comment: Do you *know* that the number of positive and negative numbers are equal?

Comment: @Henry they are not actually ! But I can't really change them, so I will just leave them as what they are.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Data**

```
x <- c(-0.5, -0.6, 0.7, 1, 1.5, 3, -5)
```

Use `rbind()` to create an alternate indices vector.

```
ind <- seq_along(x)
sort(x, decreasing = T)[rbind(ind, rev(ind))][ind]
# [1]  3.0 -5.0  1.5 -0.6  1.0 -0.5  0.7
```

---

The above method should be memory consuming because it will create a twice longer vector. To conquer it, you can set a **midpoint** as the end index. In this case, it will be `ceiling(7 / 2) = 4`.

```
n <- length(x)
ind <- 1:ceiling(n / 2) # [1] 1 2 3 4
sort(x, decreasing = T)[rbind(ind, (n:1)[ind])][1:n]
# [1]  3.0 -5.0  1.5 -0.6  1.0 -0.5  0.7
```

Answer (score 5):

We can `split` the list based on `sign` and `sort` them. We then create a new list by taking alternating elements from positive and negative lists making sure to `rev`erse the positive part of the list.

```
new_list <- sapply(split(x, sign(x)), sort)
c(rbind(rev(new_list[['1']]), new_list[['-1']]))[1:length(x)]
#[1]  3.0 -5.0  1.5 -0.6  1.0 -0.5  0.7
```

**data**

```
x <- c(-0.5, -.6, 0.7, 1, 1.5, 3, -5 )
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to `split` the `vector` by the `sign` of the `vector` into a `list` of `vector`s, loop through the `vector`, `order` the `abs`olute value of the elements in `decreasing` order, get the `lengths` of the `list` elements same with padding `NA` at the end, `rbind` them together as a `matrix`, convert it to `vector` with `c` and remove the `NA` elements with `na.omit`

```
lst1 <- sapply(split(v1, sign(v1)), function(x)  
    x[order(abs(x), decreasing = TRUE)])[2:1]
c(na.omit(c(do.call(rbind, lapply(lst1, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst1)))))))
#[1]  3.0 -5.0  1.5 -0.6  1.0 -0.5  0.7
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(-0.5, -0.6, 0.7, 1, 1.5, 3, -5)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
pos <- sort(x[x>0], decreasing = T)
neg <- sort(x[x<0], decreasing = T)

c(rbind(pos,neg))[1:length(x)]

#[1]  3.0 -0.5  1.5 -0.6  1.0 -5.0  0.7
```